# Is there an audio learning program beyond Pimsleur IV?

Tags: resource

I found Pimsleur the best method for me (others will disagree), but unfortunately the audio lessons from Pimsleur only go to level IV (Plus). Does anyone know of an audio program that's similar to, but goes further than, Pimsleur?

I've tried Rosetta Stone ... works OK, but you can't use it while you're driving to work. I've also used the pod casts from DW, but eventually ran out of content there, too.

So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **Michel Thomas Method.** [The website can be found here](http://www.michelthomas.com/learn-german.php). The Advanced course may be beyond Pimsleur IV, however I am not totally sure. I would check out reviews of the difficulties. The method is also a bit different so it may also offer another angle of approach for the learning the language, which will diversify your ability and help.

The Michel Thomas Method is unique. It uses a translation and memory based approach. You can technically use it in your car but he does not recommend it due to the distraction.

> When it comes to learning German it doesn’t get easier than the Michel
>   Thomas Method. The Michel Thomas method eases you into the German
>   language by breaking it into its component parts. You will then be
>   able to easily form your own to say what you want in German! Go from
>   absolute beginner to confident speaker—without books, homework or
>   memorizing.

**Another great resource:** [Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten](http://www.dw.de/deutsch-lernen/nachrichten/s-8030). I know it is technically from the DW, but if you haven't tried it, it is great. Many of my friends use it to improve their listening comprehension. That you can definitely use in the car. Plus it comes in Podcast and you **won't ever run out of content because it is a news program, continually being updated.**

Comment: Thanks, dude. I'll look into those. I've heard of the M Thomas approach, but haven't yet tried that.

Answer (score 1):

On YouTube there is a channel called Easy Languages.  They have a weekly man-on the street program, about 10 minutes with subtitles.  Sunday's is German.